# Sort the "edit link" column

Tags: 7, views

I'm constructing a view and i need the column "edit link" to be possible to sort (put empty fields first or last). Has anyone ever done it before ?

Thank you all
[image: screenshot of the view settings]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to mark the column as sortable in the table display options?

Comment: Actually, it's the only column that can't be marked as sortable. I added the screenshort (row "Modifier", Classable means sortable in english)

Comment: Sorting applies to fields that are part of the query. The edit link isn't part of the query, so can't be sorted on. Considering the text is 'Edit' for all of them, sorting doesn't actually make sense

Comment: Actually what i want to do is sort it in two groups : 
The first one will be with those who the user can edit
The second one with those that can't be edited by the used

Comment: I imagine you'll be custom-coding that @Ismah, it's a pretty niche requirement

Comment: Ok. By any chance, does anyone knows the variable / function that i can use in drupal to sort columns in a view ?